# How can I manipulate the tracker area to make it into a square shape?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-manipulation

I am currently working on a project on camera tracking application. I found little trouble, when I had to change the area of the detected object. The area must be transformed into a square shape so that when displayed to the screen it becomes more suitable and real.

here's a few line of code that i'm working on.

```
for cam, coll in _colls.items():
  # get all track
  tracks = coll.getAllTracks()         #tracks is a dictionary that stores the details of object that being detected.

  for x in range(len(tracks)):
    # get the selected area for croping
    edge = tracks[x]['box']

    crop_img = frame[int(edge[0]):int(edge[2]), int(edge[1]):int(edge[3])]
    # edge[0] = ymin
    # edge[1] = xmin
    # edge[2] = ymax
    # edge[3] = xmax
```

Based on that code, I've got an area where the object is being detected.

[image]

The problem is when I get the edge, it is not always in the form of a square, it can also be in a rectangular shape. Should be manipulated what it is like, so that from that edge point, can I create a square shape Like the picture below?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to compute the width and height of the area. Compute the difference between the width and the height and enlarge the smaller side of the area. For isntance:

```py
left, right, top, bottom = edge[0], edge[1], edge[2], edge[3]

width = right - left
height = bottom - top
delta = width - height

if delta > 0:
    top -= delta / 2
    bottom += delta / 2
else
    left -= -delta / 2
    right += -delta / 2

crop_img = frame[int(left):int(top), int(right):int(bottom)]
```